# Why does getelementptr + store lead to segementation fault in some cases

Tags: segmentation-fault, llvm, llvm-ir

While experimenting with LLVM I've run into a segmentation fault that I don't fully understand. For simplicity, I'm trying to allocate a chunk of memory as a large integer, and then using `getelementptr` to point to the middle of that integer and store a smaller integer (effectively like a struct but without using any struct types within LLVM). In the code example below I run into a segmentation fault, even though there should be plenty of space within the larger integer that I've allocated. (The code below has been stripped down from a larger example to a minimally reproducible case, hence the less helpful register names.)

```
define i32 @main(i32 %r34, i8** %r35) {
  call void @entry()
  ret i32 0
}

define void @entry() {
  %r5 = shl i8 3, 0
  %r7 = alloca i176
  %r10 = getelementptr i1, ptr %r7, i32 40
  store i8 %r5, ptr %r10

  ret void
}
```

What seems particularly odd to me is that if I change the `40` in the `getelementptr` call to e.g. `32`, then I don't get a segmentation fault. If I move the body of `entry` into `main`, replacing the function call, I also don't get a segmentation fault.

Does anyone know what might be going on? Am I misunderstanding something about `getelementptr`?

Comment: You're assuming that `getelementptr` will work as for a packed array of `i1` even though your code doesn't mention that you want it packed.

Comment: @arnt, please pardon my ignorance, I'm not familiar with the consequences of that assumption I've made. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I see. An array of `i1` can be stored in several ways. (This issue applies to almost all structs, not just arrays of boolean) The three most common ways are to store them as one bit per bit, one bit per byte and one bit per addressable word. Setting a single bit in an array (`a[42]=1`) costs at least two assembly instructions more in the first case than in the last, and perhaps more depending on the language's memory model. Inserting padding so each array/struct entry occupies an integer number of CPU words avoids this slowdown. Your code assumes that LLVM will pick what you expect.